# Work with WPF controls at the server side of ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wpf, quartz.net

As part of my Quartz.net job I need to load some data to WPF control and make a screenshot of it. Is there any safe way to initialize System.Windows.Application inside ASP.NET MVC application (so that I could work with WPF controls)? Should I reinitialize System.Windows.Application every time ASP.NET MVC application is reloaded?

Comment: See the [Regarding one problem of hosting a WPF User Control in an ASP.Net Web Site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/414066df-6120-4f26-ad0c-216e8ae3c068/regarding-one-problem-of-hosting-a-wpf-user-control-in-an-aspnet-web-site?forum=wpf) page on the Visual Studio Forum.

Comment: @Sheridan, the link you provided tells about XBAP which allows to use WPF controls at client side but my question is about the server side

Answer (score 2):

Imho, you should create separate wcf-service and call it from ASP.NET application. In WCF service you can use your WPF control. So you ASP.NET application will be isolated from big and dangerous WPF application.